# Two gitlab-ci runners for one project

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I used to have a project on github with a [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) and an [appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) integration service configured. Thus I was able to make sur my project was compiling ok on both *OSX* and *Windows* plateform.

I'm now working with gitlab and ci runners. I have two runners configured:

- One on a *OSX* machine
- One on a *Windows* machine

Unfortunately when I add both runners in my project settings > CI/CD > Runners settings, only one is triggered upon push (the *OSX* one).

If I disable the *OSX* runner, the *Windows* runner is triggered fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One Job is only running by one runner.

I guess you want that your Job is running twice

1. on your windows runner
2. on your osx runner

To do so

1. Tag your runners (e.g. `win` and `mac`)
2. duplicate your job for the same stage and add for your windows runner job the `win` tag and for your mac runner job the `mac` tag.

This should take care that both runners will run the job in the next pipeline.

```
stages:
  - build

mac_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - mac
  script:
    - something ...

win_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - win
  script:
    - something ...
```