# gitlab-runner run os dependent script

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

my project builds under windows and linux.I have setup a gitlab-runner on windows and one on a linux machine. Now I want to configure the ".gitlab-ci.yml" for building on both machines. BUT,  depending on the operating system, I'd like to call a different build script  for the build.

Example ".gitlab-ci.yaml" (not working)

```
mybuild:
  # on linux
  script:
    - ./build-linux.sh
  # on windows
  script
    - buildwin.bat
```

How can i achieve this in the .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The way to achieve it is to

1. give your runners unique tags. e.g. "linux-runner" and "windows-runner"
2. duplicate the job and run one job only on runners with the tag "linux-runner" and the second job only on runners with the "windows-runner" tag.

   ```
   linux build:
     stage: build
     tags:
      - linux-runner
     script:
       - ./build-linux.sh

   windows build:
     stage: build
     tags:
      - windows-runner
     script:
       - buildwin.bat
   ```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199201/2779972

Answer (score 1):

The solution generally suggested to create two jobs doesn't fit my needs. My need is to be able to use a Windows or on a Linux/MacOS runner, whatever is the one available.
My suggested trick is to create a `call` script in `/usr/local/bin` so it can mimic the Windows `call` command:

```
#/bin/bash
./$*
```

If you want to invoke Gradle wrapper for example, you can simply write in the `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
script:
- call gradle
```

it also works with a specific script (for instance "build.bat" for Windows, and "build" for MacOS/Linux):

```
script:
- call build
```

I hope that will help someone with the same need as me.

Comment: Instead of a script, an alias could also help:
`script: - ":; alias call=\"\""`

Be sure to add these quotation marks and the `:;` at the beginning. It will cause Windows to ignore it

Answer (score 1):

*This solution works similar to what @christophe-moine suggests, but without the need for creating a `call` script or alias.*

Provided that your Windows CI runner runs [Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/running-commands) (which is likely), you may simply create two scripts, e.g.

- `buildmyapp` (for Linux – note the missing extension!)
- `buildmyapp.cmd` (for Windows)

... and then execute them in GitLab CI using the Unix-style syntax, without the script extension, e.g.

```yaml
mybuild:
  script:
  - ./buildmyapp
  parallel:
    matrix:
    - PLATFORM: [linux, windows]
  tags:
  - ${PLATFORM}
```

In the `script:` block, Windows PowerShell will pick `buildmyapp.cmd` on the Windows runner, the Linux shell with pick the `buildmyapp` script on the Linux runner.

The [`parallel: matrix:` keyword in combination with `tags:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job) creates two parallel jobs that pick your CI runners via the `tags` keyword.